# How do list comprehensions work when using find_all in Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, list-comprehension

I am new to python and currently learning on "Automate The Boring Stuff" textbook. The program that I am working on should:

- Search for a category of photos in imgur
- Create a unique name and folder in the Current Working Directory
- Download all resulting images to a folder on the drive

The code I have written works, but I have a few questions.

HTML for imgur:

```
<div class="cards">
                            <div id="SZPjHwz" class="post" data-tag1="" data-tag2="">
    <a class="image-list-link" href="/gallery/SZPjHwz" data-page="0">
        <img alt="" src="//i.imgur.com/SZPjHwzb.jpg">
```

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

"""
This program:
    - Searches for a category of photos in imgur
    - Creates a unique name and folder in the Current Working Directory
    - Downloads all the resulting images to a folder on the drive (highest scoring of all time)

"""

# requests is used to retrieve the HTML of the page to download the pictures
# os is used to create the folders and save files to the drive
# sys is used to pass command line arguments to search
# bs4 BeautifulSoup is used to scrape and parse the HTML
# datetime is used to retrieve the date to create the folder

import requests, os, sys, bs4
from datetime import date

# Retrieve User Input
print("Search imgur: ")
search = input()

# Create folder destination on drive to save photos

today = date.today()
date = today.strftime("%b-%d-%Y")
folderName = date + " - imgur download - " + search
os.chdir("D:\Python\Projects - Automate the Boring Stuff with Python\Chapter 11\imgurDownloader")
if not os.path.exists(".\\" + folderName):
    os.makedirs(folderName)
    print("Directory " , folderName ,  " created ")
else:    
    print("Directory " , folderName ,  " already exists")

# Retrieve images from the link and save to the drive

res = requests.get("https://imgur.com/search?q=" + search)
res.raise_for_status()
imgurSoup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
imgurPics = [i['href'] for i in imgurSoup.find_all('a', class_='image-list-link')]

if imgurPics == []:
    print("No results found.")
else:
    print("Downloading pictures...")
    for i in range(0,len(imgurPics)):
        pictureURL = "https://imgur.com" + imgurPics[i]
        imageFile = open(os.path.join(folderName, os.path.basename(pictureURL)), "wb")
        for chunk in res.iter_content(100000):
            imageFile.write(chunk)
        imageFile.close()

    print("Download successful")
```

Questions:

1. I was able to get the links for each of the pictures inside the gallery. I'm not sure why it works though. I found the code on another stack overflow and I was confused at how they used list comprehensions to find create the list. Why doesn't the following work? Is there any way to use select?
2. What is the difference between select and findall?

   ```
   imgurPics = imgurSoup.select('a', class_='image-list-link')
   ```
3. When I download the pictures using the below code, the pictures that are saved to my folder are not openable. What is the issue here?

   ```
   for i in range(0,len(imgurPics)):
           pictureURL = "https://imgur.com" + imgurPics[i]
           imageFile = open(os.path.join(folderName, os.path.basename(pictureURL)), "wb")
           for chunk in res.iter_content(100000):
               imageFile.write(chunk)
           imageFile.close()
   ```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Usually stack overflow prefers one question per post, it makes it easier for others to find the information they are looking for and allows people to up-vote and down-vote individual Q/A that are well made. It's perfectly fine to make several different posts with different questions about the same code however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Link comprehension just puts a for loop into a one-liner. So

   ```
   imgurPics = []
   for i in imgurSoup.find_all('a', class_='image-list-link'):
       imgurPics.append(i['href']
   ```

is the same as list comprehension...

```
imgurPics = [i['href'] for i in imgurSoup.find_all('a', class_='image-list-link')]
```

2.`.find_all` and `select` are essentially the same idea. It's just a matter of `select` accepts CSS selectors. I personally am more comfortable with `.find_all()` because that what I learned first. If you wanted to use `select`, you can do `imgurPics = [i['href'] for i in imgurSoup.select('a.image-list-link')]`

3. you links are links to gallerias, not individual pics. So you need to pull and save an individual pic. So what you are really after is `<img alt="" src="//i.imgur.com/SZPjHwzb.jpg">`, not the `href`. Secondly, you don't read in that response. you have `res.iter_content(100000)`, but that is in reference to `res = requests.get("https://imgur.com/search?q=" + search)`. You need to get the image from that link you are iterating through.
4. Be careful with using variables that have the same names as functions/modules. You do `from datetime import date`, but then use `date = today.strftime("%b-%d-%Y")`. I'd say try to avoid that. I changed the variable to `dateStr`
5. No need to create index range when looping (unless you are using or need the index with the element, or having a counter. Even then, if I need the index with it, then I'd just use `enumerate()`), But no need to do a for loop on `i in range(0,len(imgurPics))`. Just simply do `for i in imgurPics`. That will loop through the entire list.

So look through the code. I noted where I made changes so you can see.

```
import requests, os, sys, bs4
from datetime import date

# Retrieve User Input
search = input("Search imgur:\n\n") #<--- made change here. You can do what you had in 1 line

# Create folder destination on drive to save photos
today = date.today()
dateStr = today.strftime("%b-%d-%Y")  #<--- changed the variable name
folderName = dateStr + " - imgur download - " + search
os.chdir("D:\Python\Projects - Automate the Boring Stuff with Python\Chapter 11\imgurDownloader")
if not os.path.exists(".\\" + folderName):
    os.makedirs(folderName)
    print("Directory " , folderName ,  " created ")
else:    
    print("Directory " , folderName ,  " already exists")

# Retrieve images from the link and save to the drive

res = requests.get("https://imgur.com/search?q=" + search)
res.raise_for_status()
imgurSoup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
imgurPics = [i['src'] for i in imgurSoup.find_all('img') if 'loaders' not in i['src']] #<-- change here to get the img tag with the src attribute, which is the link to the image. This will possibly include an extra link that we don't want, so I added the if part as well

if imgurPics == []:
    print("No results found.")
else:
    print("Downloading pictures...")
    for pic in imgurPics:  #<--- change the loop syntax slightly
        pictureURL = "https:" + pic  #<--- had to change this slightly
        resPic = requests.get(pictureURL)  #<--- added this like to pull the image http
        imageFile = open(os.path.join(folderName, os.path.basename(pictureURL)), "wb")
        for chunk in resPic.iter_content(100000): #<--- need to point to that image http repsonse, so used the response I got 2 lines up `resPic`
            imageFile.write(chunk)
        imageFile.close()

    print("Download successful")
```